# Multilingual WordPress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual

Right now we have 5 WordPress sites in different languages, which we consider to merge into one site. I haven't tried any multilingual since few years, but I seem to recall those I tried before had various problems. 
So has they improved enough to actually be worth using? And if so, which can you recommend, that works with Divi Woocommerce and most plugins?

Comment: Depends very much on what themes you use, or how much custom code you got there. The plugins usually needs twitching, or cover only certain themes that come with a language pack plugin. It would be too much work if you ask me. A better alternative is to create a multilingual site from scratch, using a theme that has this option built-in.

Comment: Thanks, didn't consider that some themes come with multilingual support.. that is something worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I use for many projects WPML, and is the best. It's fully compatible with Woocommerce and Divi. You can find more informations here: https://wpml.org/
It's compatible with Divi (except some features) and you can find functionalities that are not yet compatible on this page: https://wpml.org/documentation/theme-compatibility/divi-builder/

Just i recommend reading and studying wpml's documentation before launching it because there are many configurations and features that are not easy to use. Once we understand it's really relevant.